# Error in GraphQL query it says Unknown type "ContentfulSizes"

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, contentful

when I try to link my gatsby project with my self -created Contentful space, it shows this issue all the time

But when I try to link my gatsby to a contentful spaces with I created with their templates or examples, it runs fine

But for self created spaces, it shows this error....

Any solutions?

---

ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Unknown type "ContentfulSizes". Did you mean "ContentfulSecondTry", "ContentfulContentType", or "ContentfulSecondTryEdge"?

File: node_modules\gatsby-source-contentful\src\fragments.js:4:46

Comment: Do you have a type called `ContentfulSizes`?

Answer (score 8):

Go into your Contentful space, click on Media, and add a dummy image just as a placeholder.

For more details read this: 
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15344#issuecomment-508242874

Comment: This should only fix the problem if the thing undefined was a single field. And in that case you can easily write a resolver without cluttering your contentfulspace with unneccessary images.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to the answer by **Will Sherman**, make sure that you publish the image.

On the top right side of the page, you'll see a DRAFT dropdown button. Click on it and select PUBLISH.

Then run `gatsby develop` again on your local machine